# Incorrect local variable value after pthread_join

Tags: c, pthreads, nptl, pthread-exit

I am trying to sum up 1000 elements integer array(where each element is 1) with pthread library by splitting the array in to segments of size 10. So effectively, 100 threads are being used to do that. The results of this parallel operation is as expected (1000). But interestingly, the sequential sum which I calculated before creating the threads is being set to zero after my first call to `pthread_join()`. Not sure if I am missing something here. Can someone spot the bug here?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SEGMENT_SIZE 10
#define NUM_THREADS 100
int *array = NULL;

void* segment_sum(void *args)
{
        int index = (int)args;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = index * SEGMENT_SIZE; i < (index + 1) * SEGMENT_SIZE; i++) {
                sum += array[i];
        }

        return (void *)sum;
}

int main()
{
        pthread_t thread[NUM_THREADS];
        int res = 0;
        int seq_res = 0;
        int par_res = 0;

        array = calloc(1, sizeof(int) * NUM_THREADS * SEGMENT_SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS * SEGMENT_SIZE; i++) {
                array[i] = 1;
                seq_res += 1;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
                res = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, segment_sum, (void *)i);
                if (res != 0) {
                        printf("\nError creating new thread");
                }
        }

        printf("\nindex = %d", seq_res);                // the sequential sum here is 1000

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
                int sum = 0;
                res = pthread_join(thread[i], (void **)&sum);
                if (res != 0) {
                        printf("\nError creating new thread");
                }
                printf("\nindex = %d", seq_res);        // Here it is becoming zero!!!

                par_res += sum;
        }

        printf("\nmultithreaded sum: %d single threaded sum: %d\n", par_res, seq_res);
}
```

Comment: `(void **) &sum` casts a pointer to an int to a pointer to a pointer to void, which is not going to work, and if ints are 32 bits but pointers 64 bits, you're probably going to trample on memory, so seeing `seq_res` change is one possible outcome. Also, a pthread should return a value through `pthread_exit()`.

Comment: Thanks Ken,You are right. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile your program, try as much as possible to eliminate
the warnings as they often point out non portable behaviors or hidden
errors. Here the compilation points out the following:

```
pte.c: In function 'segment_sum':
pte.c:11:21: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   11 |         int index = (int)args;
      |                     ^
pte.c:18:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   18 |         return (void *)sum;
      |                ^
pte.c: In function 'main':
pte.c:36:69: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   36 |                 res = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, segment_sum, (void *)i);
      |                                                                     ^
```

The parameter passed to the threads is a cast of a pointer into an "int". It is
advised to pass the address of an "int". Hence, you can define a per-thread
context:

```
struct thd_ctx {
  pthread_t thread;
  int index;
  int sum;
};
```

pthread_join() is passed the address of a pointer which will get the address
of the memory location into which the thread stored its result. The thread must
return the address of this memory location, not the value stored into it.
Moreover, the thread should not return the address of an automatic variable
(i.e. in its stack) as it is unspecified. The result must be the address
of a global variable (or "something" visible from the joining thread) returned either directly or through [pthread_exit()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_exit). In this enhancement of the program, we use the address of the "sum" field in the thread's context:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SEGMENT_SIZE 10
#define NUM_THREADS 100
int *array = NULL;


struct thd_ctx {
  pthread_t thread;
  int index;
  int sum;
};


void *segment_sum(void *args)
{
  int i;
  struct thd_ctx *ctx = (struct thd_ctx *)args;

  ctx->sum = 0;

  for (i = ctx->index * SEGMENT_SIZE; i < (ctx->index + 1) * SEGMENT_SIZE; i++) {
    ctx->sum += array[i];
  }

  return (void *)&(ctx->sum);
}


int main(void)
{
  struct thd_ctx thd_ctx[NUM_THREADS];
  int res = 0;
  int seq_res = 0;
  int par_res = 0;
  int i;

  array = calloc(1, sizeof(int) * NUM_THREADS * SEGMENT_SIZE);
  if (!array) {
    fprintf(stderr, "calloc(): error %d\n", errno);
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS * SEGMENT_SIZE; i++) {
    array[i] = 1;
    seq_res += 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    thd_ctx[i].index = i;
    res = pthread_create(&(thd_ctx[i].thread), NULL, segment_sum, (void *)&(thd_ctx[i]));
    if (res != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %d creating new thread#%d\n", res, i);
      free(array);
      return 1;
    }
  }

  printf("Index = %d\n", seq_res);   // the sequential sum here is 1000

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    int *sum = 0;
    res = pthread_join(thd_ctx[i].thread, (void **)&(sum));
    if (res != 0) {
      printf("Error %d joining thread#%d", res, i);
      free(array);
      return 1;
    }

    par_res += *sum;

    printf("sum = %d\n", par_res);
  }

  printf("\nMultithreaded sum: %d single threaded sum: %d\n", par_res, seq_res);

  free(array);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed solution. Below is the snippet from `man pthread_exit` 

`NOTES
       Performing  a  return  from the start function of any thread other than the main thread results in an implicit
       call to pthread_exit(), using the function's return value as the thread's exit status.`

With the help of thread context, isn't it good idea to return only failure/success status from `segment_sum`  instead of returning the actual computation value? Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, the exit status should only say everything went OK/KO. I just tried to propose an enhancement of your code without redesigning everything as the goal was to fix the computation error.

Comment: The other important point from the [manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html) is in the NOTES section: "The value pointed to by retval should not be located on the calling thread's stack, since the contents of that stack are undefined after the thread terminates."

Comment: Sure thanks again, converted my sample to use the thread_ctx.